# How to extend std::vector constructors for custom elements

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

Have a Union typedef and want to create a vector of that Union Type, but want to load a vector of other type to it, error says I need a constructor.

union:

```
typedef union
{
  uin32_t uin;
  int32_t sin;
  float   flt;
  uitn8_t u8n[4];
}rDATA
```

Underlying architecture is 32 bits, so the last element does cover all above types, I am receiving data in a float array, I can convert that float array to a vector, but can't seem to load the data into a rDATA vector, so:

```
 vector<float> vector_array(&array[0], &array[0] + array_size) 
 std::vector<LEAP_DATA_UNIT> DATA_vector(vector_array)
```

Comment: Do note that type punning through a union has undefined behavior in C++ unless you are inspecting the initial common sequence of members of standard layout classes.

Comment: Code was badly damaged in translation. Please fix the typos and confirm that `LEAP_DATA_UNIT` and `rDATA` are the same.

Comment: `uin32_t`, `uitn8_t` seriously??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option that produces very readable code, is to create an iterator that adapts the source type (e.g. `float`) to the `union` type. This allows the direct use of the regular `std::vector` constructor.

The following code gives an idea of how it might work. You could generalize it to take a `lambda` that could do an arbitrary transformation on an element. You would also probably want to make a `make_iterator_adaptor` method for easy creation.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

union Data {
    uint32_t uin;
    int32_t sin;
    float fin;
    uint8_t u8n[4];
};

template<class base_iterator>
struct iterator_adaptor {
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
    using different_type = typename base_iterator::difference_type;
    using value_type = Data;
    using pointer = Data*;
    using reference = Data&;

    iterator_adaptor(base_iterator iter)
        : iter_(iter) {
    }

    value_type operator*() const {
        Data d;
        d.fin = *iter_;
        return d;
    }

    iterator_adaptor& operator++() {
        ++iter_;
        return *this;
    }

    iterator_adaptor operator++(int) {
        iterator_adaptor tmp = *this;
        ++(*this);
        return tmp;
    }

    friend bool operator==(const iterator_adaptor& a, const iterator_adaptor& b) {
        return a.iter_ == b.iter_;
    }

    friend bool operator!=(const iterator_adaptor& a, const iterator_adaptor& b) {
        return not (a == b);
    }

private:
    base_iterator iter_;
};

namespace std {
template<class T>
struct iterator_traits<iterator_adaptor<T>> {
    using value_type = typename iterator_adaptor<T>::value_type;
    using difference_type = typename iterator_adaptor<T>::different_type;
    using iterator_category = typename iterator_adaptor<T>::iterator_category;
    using pointer = typename iterator_adaptor<T>::pointer;
    using reference = typename iterator_adaptor<T>::reference;
};
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<float> floats = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };
    std::vector<Data> data(iterator_adaptor(floats.begin()), iterator_adaptor(floats.end()));

    for (auto i = 0; i < floats.size(); ++i)
        assert(floats[i] == data[i].fin);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to convert each float to the `union` type and then insert that into the vector. The code won't look streamlined, but the compiler will end up pushing the `float`s directly into the `vector` so it doesn't matter. Something like the following should be standards compliant.

```cpp
union Data {
    uint32_t uin;
    int32_t sin;
    float fin;
    uint8_t u8n[4];
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<float> a(10);
    std::vector<Data> b;
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b), [](float x) {
        Data u;
        u.fin = x;
        return u;
    });
}
```

And, you will probably have better luck if you provide a minimal, reproducible example that compiles. Makes it a lot easier to provide help.